# Background image changes when hovering on link, want image to remain, until other link is hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, state

Here the code, `.bg1` class contains an image and when applied to a link, hovering  covers background with image, what I am asking is how do I make that background image remain until other item is hovered.

```
<html>
<head>
<script 
type="text/javascript"  src="
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<style>

 >/*text fade into center*******************************************/

.animated{

-webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;
-moz-animation-fill-mode:both;
 -ms-animation-fill-mode:both;
 -o-animation-fill-mode:both;
animation-fill-mode:both;
-webkit-animation-duration:1s;
-moz-animation-duration:1s;
-ms-animation-duration:1s;
-o-animation-duration:1s;
animation-duration:1s;  
}

.animated3{

-webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;
-moz-animation-fill-mode:both;
-ms-animation-fill-mode:both;
-o-animation-fill-mode:both;
animation-fill-mode:both;
-webkit-animation-duration:1s;
-moz-animation-duration:1s;
-ms-animation-duration:1s;
-o-animation-duration:1s;
animation-duration:1s;
-webkit-animation-delay:1s;
-moz-animation-delay:1s;
-ms-animation-delay:1s;
-o-animation-delay:1s;
animation-delay:1s;   
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInLeft {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-20px);
}   100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
}
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeInLeft {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-20px);
}

100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
}
}

@-o-keyframes fadeInLeft {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transform: translateX(-20px);
}

100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
}
}

@keyframes fadeInLeft {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-20px);
}

100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
}
}

.fadeInLeft {
-webkit-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
-moz-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
-o-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
animation-name: fadeInLeft;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes fadeOutLeft {
    0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
}

100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-20px);
}
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeOutLeft {
0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
}

100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-20px);
}
}

@-o-keyframes fadeOutLeft {
0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
}

100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transform: translateX(-20px);
}
}

@keyframes fadeOutLeft {
0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
}

100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-20px);
}
}

.fadeOutLeft {
-webkit-animation-name: fadeOutLeft;
-moz-animation-name: fadeOutLeft;
-o-animation-name: fadeOutLeft;
animation-name: fadeOutLeft;
-webkit-animation-duration:5s;
-moz-animation-duration:5s;
-ms-animation-duration:5s;
-o-animation-duration:5s;
animation-duration:5s;  
}



>/*initial text on page load//////////////////////////////////////////*/

    .container 
    {position: fixed; top: 
    25%; left: 10%; 
    z-index:-2; 
    }

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@keyframes fadeinleft {from { transform:translateX(-30px)} 
to { transform:translate(0px)}} 

.fade-in {
  opacity:0; 
  -webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;  
  -moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
  animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;

  -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;

  -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
  -moz-animation-duration:1s;
  animation-duration:1s;}

  .fade-in:hover{
  opacity:0; 
  -webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;  
  -moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
  animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;

  -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;

  -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
  -moz-animation-duration:1s;
  animation-duration:1s;

}
.fadeout{
   opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;}
 .fadeout:hover
 {opacity :0;}


.box{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10%;
  float: left;
  background: transparent;
  font-size:50px;
  font-family:"Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", 
 "DejaVu Sans      Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 2px 1px black;
 color:grey;
}
>/*underline*//////////////////////////////////////

  .underlined-example {
   background-color: transparent;
   position:fixed;
}

.underlined-example {
position: relative;
color: gray;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight:bold;
  display:inline;

}

.underlined-example:hover {
color: gray;
}

.underlined-example:before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 2px;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: blue;
  visibility: hidden;


 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;

-webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
-moz-transform: scaleX(0);
-o-transform: scaleX(0);
transform: scaleX(0);
}

.underlined-example:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  -moz-transform: scaleX(1);
  -o-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
>/*dropdown menu...............................................*/

ul#mainNav > li {
float:left;
display:inline;
position:relative;
background-color:transparent;
cursor: pointer;
margin: 32px;
margin-top:-30;

}
.contain{
max-width:1300px;
min-width:1300px;
margin-left:283px;

}
ul#mainNav > li:hover {
background:transparent;
color:gray;
 cursor: pointer;

}
ul#mainNav > li:hover ul {
visibility: visible;
opacity: 1;
transition-delay: 0s, 0s;

}
ul#mainNav li ul {
position:absolute;
float:left;
height:0;
padding:15px 0px; 
margin:0 ;
min-height: 300px;
min-width:100px;
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;
transition-property: opacity, visibility;
transition-duration: .4s, 0s;
transition-delay: 0s, .4s;
line-height: 2;

}
ul#mainNav ul li {   
background-color:transparent;

}
ul#mainNav ul li:hover {
 color:gray;

}
.bg1:hover:after{
content:'';
z-index: -1;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background:url(gif2.gif) no-repeat center;
background-size:cover;
line-height: 2;
-webkit-animation: fadeInLeft ;
   -moz-animation: fadeInLeft ;
    -ms-animation: fadeInLeft ;
     -o-animation: fadeInLeft ; 
        animation: fadeInLeft ;
-webkit-animation-duration:1s;
-moz-animation-duration:1s;
-ms-animation-duration:1s;
-o-animation-duration:1s;
animation-duration:1s;  


}

>/*img size logo/////////////////////////////////////////*/


.logo{
padding:0 0 0 780px;
position:relative;


}

>/*page load up fades in////////////////////////////////////////////*/

.pageload{ 

-webkit-animation: fadein 1s;
   -moz-animation: fadein 1s;
    -ms-animation: fadein 1s;
     -o-animation: fadein 1s; 
        animation: fadein 1s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
from { opacity: 0; }
to   { opacity: 1; }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
from { opacity: 0; }
to   { opacity: 1; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
from { opacity: 0; }
to   { opacity: 1; }
}

@-ms-keyframes fadein {
from { opacity: 0; }
to   { opacity: 1; }
}

@-o-keyframes fadein {
from { opacity: 0; }
to   { opacity: 1; }

 >/*11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111*/


</style>

<div class="pageload">
<body>
<script>

</script>

<div class="logo">
<img src="C:\Users\executive jewelry\Desktop\SITE\logo.png"width="320" >
</div>
<div class="contain">
<ul id="mainNav">
<li class="data-bkg bg1 underlined-example" href="">JEWELRY</l>
     <ul>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
    </ul>        
 </li> 
 <li href="" class="underlined-example">ENGAGEMENT</l>
    <ul>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
    </ul>        
</li>
<li href="" class="underlined-example">DIAMONDS</l>
    <ul>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
    </ul>        
 </li>
 <li href="" class="underlined-example">WATCHES</l>
    <ul>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
    </ul>        
</li>
 <li href="" class="underlined-example">CUSTOM CAD</l>
    <ul>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
    </ul>        
</li>
 <li href="" class="underlined-example">REPAIR</l>
    <ul>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
    </ul>        
</li>
 <li href="" class="underlined-example">APPRAISAL</l>
    <ul>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
    </ul>        
</li>
 <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
    <ul>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
    </ul>        
</li>
 <li href="" class="underlined-example">CONTACT</l>
    <ul>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
    </ul>        
</li>
    </div> 
<div class="container box animated fadeInLeft">
     FOR OVER 30 YEARS, EXECUTIVE JEWELERS
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: post your css code

Comment: You say "So I added a class to a link".  What links?

Comment: you posted the most irrelevant code for this, post your css code and any jquery you have

Comment: `html` ta Question is not valid

Comment: All kinds of problems in that HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turn out I made a novice mistake, boy was it dumb. Thank you all for hour help.

All I needed to do was was change the order  of the z-index, so when I hovered over a link the image remained over any item below its z-index, then by applying a higher z-index rating to other links, during hover it would change to that. This may not be the most effective way to do this but it works fine. Im relatively new to web development.